# lodash _.toArray with placeholders

Tags: javascript, lodash

is there a way to convert a JS object to an array where each key is an an index into the array, filling in placeholders?

For instance, if you have something like

```
var obj = {0: 'asdf', 2: 'zxcv'}
```

I'd like to get out something like

```
['asdf', null, 'zxcv']
```

I tried `_.toArray(obj)` with Lo-Dash but this just returns `['asdf', 'zxcv']`

Comment: add a length property before you convert to an array. if you have number keys and a length, realArray=[].slice.call(fakeArray) works...

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like this :

```
var obj = {0: 'asdf', 2: 'zxcv'}
var array =[];
for (var key in obj) {
     array[key]=obj[key]
}
```

Length of this array is 3 and  contains this :

```
Array : ["asdf", undefined × 1, "zxcv"]
```

Comment: hoping for a more elegant solution than a loop

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is finding the length of the future array. As long as the object has only numeric keys in string form, `Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(obj)) + 1` should do it.

```js
const obj = {0: 'asdf', 2: 'zxcv', 50: 'hgfd', 300: 'jkhf' };

console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(obj)) + 1);
```

If we know the length we can use @dandavis method:

```js
const obj = {0: 'asdf', 2: 'zxcv', 10: 'hgfd' };

const result = [].slice.call(Object.assign({ 
  length: Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(obj)) + 1}, obj));

console.log(result);
```

If you want `null` instead of `undefined` you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const obj = {0: 'asdf', 2: 'zxcv', 10: 'hgfd' };

const result = Array.from({
  length: Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(obj)) + 1
}, (v, k) => obj.hasOwnProperty(k) ? obj[k] : null);

console.log(result);
```